# LCASE, UCASE, Number, Special Characters and Minimum of 6 Characters PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I was able to generate auto generated password using PHP.

I'm using this code:

```
$random = str_shuffle('abcdefghjklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567890!$%^&!$%^&');
$auto_generate_password = substr($random, 0, 10);
$auto_generate_password = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $auto_generate_password);
```

And the output of this is:

[image]

However, a number is missing. Is there missing on my current code?

There should be

- Lower Case
- Upper Case
- Number
- Special Characters and minimum of 6 characters in my generated password

But on my current output there is a number missing.

Comment: What part of the code above do you think is enforcing any kind of requirements? Do you understand what the code is doing?

Answer (score 1):

if no number is in the first 10 positions of the array shuffle it will not be one, in fact the same applies to the other sub-sets. Another point, maybe intended, its that there will only be at the most 1 of each char (been 'a' for ex).

1. Check you have all requirement or repeat.
2. Maybe have sub-sets